# Wordpress : How to send auto reply to the customer filling out the form using gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Can anyone please let me know on "How to send auto reply to the customer filling out the form using gravity forms?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Notifications" in the Form Settings menu. Select "Add New". For the "Send To" option, choose "Select a field", then select the email field from your form. You can fill out the other settings as needed.

Comment: Hi Johny, Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms uses WordPress' built-in wp-mail.php sendmail file to send e-mails. You might want to check PHP logs to see if there is something wrong. If everything is set-up correctly, and your server isn't creating errors, then the SMTP plugins available might help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o9ByAvyOAE